# Sending input to a webpage and reaching for output via Python

Tags: python, urllib2

I am building a program in Python that needs to go through this webpage: http://circe.med.uniroma1.it/proABC/index.php

Instead of doing it manually, I wonder how do you send information to the website ? There are two DNA sequences from files, that can be used directly from the file or stored as two `strings` in Python.

And in the opposite way, how do you access the results through Python ? (I need the positions where there is a pic) Is `urllib2` suitable for this ?

Here are two sequences as example :

```
light = 'DIQMTQSPASLSASVGETVTITCRASGNIHNYLAWYQQKQGKSPQLLVYYTTTLADGVPSRFSGSGSGTQYSLKINSLQPEDFGSYYCQHFWSTPRTFGGGTKLEIKRADAAPTVSIFPPSSEQLTSGGASVVCFLNNFYPKDINVKWKIDGSERQNGVLNSWTDQDSKDSTYSMSSTLTLTKDEYERHNSYTCEATHKTSTSPIVKSFNRNEC'

heavy = 'QVQLKESGPGLVAPSQSLSITCTVSGFSLTGYGVNWVRQPPGKGLEWLGMIWGDGNTDYNSALKSRLSISKDNSKSQVFLKMNSLHTDDTARYYCARERDYRLDYWGQGTTLTVSSASTTPPSVFPLAPGSAAQTNSMVTLGCLVKGYFPEPVTVTWNSGSLSSGVHTFPAVLQSDLYTLSSSVTVPSSPRPSETVTCNVAHPASSTKVDKKIVPRDC'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use robobrowser. Please see the github page:
https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser

Example code:

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)
browser.open('http://circe.med.uniroma1.it/proABC/index.php')
form = browser.get_forms()[1]
# Now you can fill each elements in form as given below
form['light']='DIQMTQSPASLSASVGETVTITCRASGNIHNYLAWYQQKQGKSPQLLVYYTTTLADGVPSRFSGSGSGTQYSLKINSLQPEDFGSYYCQHFWSTPRTFGGGTKLEIKRADAAPTVSIFPPSSEQLTSGGASVVCFLNNFYPKDINVKWKIDGSERQNGVLNSWTDQDSKDSTYSMSSTLTLTKDEYERHNSYTCEATHKTSTSPIVKSFNRNEC'
form['heavy']='QVQLKESGPGLVAPSQSLSITCTVSGFSLTGYGVNWVRQPPGKGLEWLGMIWGDGNTDYNSALKSRLSISKDNSKSQVFLKMNSLHTDDTARYYCARERDYRLDYWGQGTTLTVSSASTTPPSVFPLAPGSAAQTNSMVTLGCLVKGYFPEPVTVTWNSGSLSSGVHTFPAVLQSDLYTLSSSVTVPSSPRPSETVTCNVAHPASSTKVDKKIVPRDC'
```

and so on.. You can simply use `form['element-name']` to fill out the form.

Finally submit the form after filling all the mandatory fields:

```
 browser.submit_form(form)
```

Please read see the [Github Readme](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser) for more info on how to access the result.

Comment: Thanks for this, but none of the code example they gave seems to work. Running them keep giving me `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` Do you have a example code that should work ?

Comment: Ok, but I'm sorry, the documentation is very short and the examples given are not working so I cannot figure out how to use this module... I tried your code, but I can't see any results. Don't you know where I could find more information about this module, not only in the readme ?